# Change li background on nav using waypoints

Tags: jquery, html-lists, background-color, jquery-waypoints

My jquery knowledge is soft at best.

I cant figure this out.  Basically I have a simple sticky horizontal nav bar using UL LI on a long page.  I want the nav bar li items to change color depending on what section of the page they are viewing.  Similar to this page http://www.pandlmedia.com/index.php/index_new but only its horizontal and instead of the link changing color I want the entire bg of the li item to change white.

I am attempting to toggleclass on the .menu ul li a item to a new class .menuwhite ul li a to change the background from blue to white but its not working.  Any help into what I'm doing wrong here?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rRt/

```
    $(".wphistory").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
       if (direction === 'down') {
         $('#menu').toggleClass('menuwhite');
       }
       else {
         $('#menu').removeClass('menuwhite');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things. That `event` parameter seems to be screwing the function.
And also, which is a big question, why do you toggle class on `#menu` when your div is actually `.menu` ? :) (class not ID). Additionally:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rRt/3/

Comment: First off, thanks for the help Kaloyan and good catch.. I must have just miss-typed it as an id instead of a class.  This brings up something else I didn't think ahead on.  Changing the class at the .menu level changes the entire menu and text white.  Whereas, I only want the single li item for "overview" to change to white background with blue text.

Comment: Check this, I've added comments for you to see what I'm doing - http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rRt/5/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding the comments so I could understand.  Adding background-color:#white !important gives me the effect I need. http://jsfiddle.net/AGhyM/1/  Thanks again for all the help Kaloyan

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you understood what I was doing since the function is a bit messy. :D